# Extends + implements, a question on good design principles

Tags: php, interface

--- code changed ---

Suppose i have an interface and two classes, one of which extends the other one:

```
interface EncryptionModule {
    public function setup();

    public function encrypt($originalString);

    public function decrypt($encryptedString);
}

class GeneralOneWayHashingModule {
    public static $encryptionType = ALG_TYPE_HASH_FUNCTION;
    protected $salt;

    public function setSalt($salt) {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }


    public function decrypt($encryptedString) {
        throw new Exception(__CLASS__ . ' ' . __LINE__ . ': cannot reverse an hash function ');
    }
}

class BCryptHashingModule extends GeneralOneWayHashingModule implements GeneralOneWayHashingModule {
    protected $cost;

    public function setup() {
        $this->cost = 10;
    }

    public function setCost($cost) {
        $this->cost = $cost;
    }

    public function encrypt($originalString) {
        return crypt($originalString, '$2a$' . str_pad($this->cost, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '$' . $this->salt);
    }
}
```

I wonder which one of the two classes should implement EncryptionModule interface.. the extending one (this is my choice)? Both classes, maybe with GeneralOneWayHashingModule declared as abstract and implementing all functions declared in EncryptionModule? Only the extended one?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an architecture and design question. These usually require more information than a couple of class names to answer.

Comment: Apart from that everyone said, hashing is not encrypting. I guess your interface EncryptionModule would have both `crypt()` and `decrypt()`, and that's not possible with a OneWayHashing algorithm. So before implementing the interface, I would rename it to HashingModule

Comment: You're right Carlos, i agree with you. But for my purposes it's not a problem to simply rise an exception when decrypt() is called on a module which implements a hashing function. Anyway: i'm editing my question to be more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question whether GeneralOneWayHashingModule should be abstract is unrelated to the other question: whether it should implement this interface. And the answer to both is: It depends on the [Responsibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) of the classes, whether it is intended to be instantiated, and possibly [other decisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

I could give a better answer if I knew what each class is for and which methods it has.

**EDIT** after code-update

I see several issues here:

- Why do you call the class *…Module*? I do not think it is a module, but a regular class. Its responsibility is encrypting stuff. I would rather call it `Encryption` (Names are extremely important to me, they will tell me what this class is for, even if I'm concentrating on something else - which is usually the case when I'm using a class)
- As [Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592540/carlos-campderros) points out correctly in a comment to your question Encryption != Hashing and Encryption is by definition reverseable, whereas hashing is not, the two classes should not be extending each other.
- What is the purpose of the `setup()` function? I think you added that function because you noticed that some sub-class needs it for its implementation. The question should rather be: Do all encryption functions have a set-up routine? Is it mandatory? I do not think so.
- Another problem you have is that you want some of your encryption routines to use salt, whereas others do not seem to need one. Since salt is usually not re-used (i.e. you usually have a new salt for each encryption), it should not be a class member, otherwise your class has a *state* which is not what you want (i.e. `$encryption` can no longer `encrypt()` 2 strings in a row, its *state* has to be changed - `setSalt()` has to be called - for it to be able to encrypt the second string).
- But the real question is: What do you need this class structure for? For testing/showcasing different algorithms or for storing/verifying passwords? If you just want to implement password verification, you are over-engineering, you could rather use something like this:

  > ```
  > class User {
  >     public function encryptPassword($password, $salt) {
  >         // …
  >     }
  >     public function verifyPassword($password, $salt, $encryptedPassword);
  >         return $encryptedPassword == self::encryptPassword($password, $salt);
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

Comment: I changed the code - sorry for not have being more clear since the beginning. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but i think you just miss the point. I accept all of your observation, and thanks for giving me your point of view, but my question was not about hashing and/or encryption. I could provide an example with mammals, quadrupeds and dogs and my question would be the same.

Comment: @geezmo: But then my answer would be the same: You cannot solve such things generally, it always depends on the context - and on the context only. That's why I asked for more information in the first place. A good illustration of this heavy dependency on context is the question "Is a circle an ellipse?". The wikipedia entry presents a dozen solutions to this simple question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Comment: I'd +1 your answer if i could, but i cannot do it (i'm new here and i do not have enough reputation). I'll do it as soon as i can, for your tips are precious. I'm still quite sure about the generality of my question ("if i use general classes for sharing code and interfaces for defining behaviours, interfaces must be implemented by general classes or by concrete implementations whose extend them?"), but i'll follow your links immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the other classes which inherit from `GeneralOneWayHashingModule`, if they all implements the `EncryptionModule` interface, then `GeneralOneWayHashingModule` should "implements" it too.

And, by the way, if `GeneralOneWayHashingModule` "implements" the `EncryptionModule`, then `BCryptHashingModule` "implements" it too, because it inherits of it (the "extends" key word).

Comment: I changed the code - sorry for not have being more clear since the beginning. :-)

Comment: Then I think `GeneralOneWayHashingModule` should implements `EncryptionModule` and be an abstract class. This way you don't have to define `encrypt` in it.

Comment: Thanks Simon! Actually, the purpose of GeneralOneWayHashingModule is to avoid code repetition - it actually shares code with classes whose extend it. The behaviuor that concrete classes should follow is entirely described by the interface. GeneralOneWayHashingModule class could implement the interface, but declaring the encrypt() method as abstract in GeneralOneWayHashingModule class is not the same as implementing the interface with BCryptHashingModule directly?

Comment: Not exactly, if you're doing it, any `GeneralOneWayHashingModule` subclass will not by automagically an `EncryptionModule`. You have to keep in mind that abstractions are particularly useful when you don't know the "exact" (called "dynamic") type of an object. For instance, a function could take a `GeneralOneWayHashingModule` as argument, if the `GeneralOneWayHashingModule` implements the `EncryptionModule` interface, then you don't have to know what subclass of `GeneralOneWayHashingModule` it is to use the `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods.